# refresh passed values to id using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

im retrieving live data from my database which refreshes every second. In my php i iterate all the and return it to the html. So the table is refreshed each second.

in my php

```
foreach ($values as $rate) {
 echo' <tr>
       <td class="symbol"> '.$rate['symbol'].'</td>
            <td class="high">
                 <a class="high">'.$rate['high'].'</a>
            </td>
            <td class="low">
                <a class="low">'.$rate['low'].'</a>
            </td>
            <td>
                 '.$rate['changes'].'
            </td>
            </tr>'
            ;
 } 

       }
```

and i add that to a div and it works without any problem

```
$('#livedata').html(lived);
```

so when a a user clicks on high or low values i show a dialog box to the users with those values

```
   $(document).on("click",".high",function() {
       var high =  $(this).closest('tr').children('td.high').text();
       var low=  $(this).closest('tr').children('td.low').text();

        $('#high').html(high);
        $('#low').html(low);
     $( "#dialog" ).dialog();
    });
```

the above code also works but i need the high and low values in the dialog box to change according to the table which refreshes each second.

can someone help me how to achieve this?

Comment: create a timer (using `setInterval`), take references to the elements (the `$('#high')` and `$('#low')`) saved somewhere and update normally.

Comment: When you delegate a handler for `.high`, `this` will refer to the clicked `.high` element inside the handler... no need to find it again, you can simply write `var high =  `$(this).text()`.

Comment: *"i need the high and low values in the dialog box to change according to the table which refreshes each second."* - ok. What dialogue box, how are you creating it..? Is it always visible..? Can you elaborate..?

Comment: @TJ its like this, in the table the high and low values keep on changing every second. So for an example in a row the high value is 1.5 and the low value is 1.24. so which i trigger the slick event, to show the dialogbox i show the user some additional details plus the current high and low values. in the mean time the high has become 2.8 and low is 1.2. i need the user to see the new values each time its updated when he is viewing the dialogbox. its only visible when the user clicks. if you check my last code block ` $( "#dialog" ).dialog();`

Comment: i show the user a form designed in `#dialog` the values are added based on the click

Comment: @KingKing i did try that but i need only to show the clicked value not all